# My service does not start on Windows 2008 (it works on Windows 2003)

Tags: service, windows-server-2008, uac

When we install our product on Windows 2008 SP2, couple of services fail to start.  After trying different things, we figured out that these service were able to start when "Log on as" is set to "Local system account".

This service does need to run as a specific user because it requires access to secure resources.  The service did run just fine under this special user account under Windows 2003.  I am thinking the problem is related to UAC (user access control).

Under interactive mode one can elevate permission by answering the security dialog box.  How to do the same for a service?  How to configure the service so it runs with necessary permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an entry to your service application's assembly manifest. Include a **requestedExecutionLevel** of **requireAdministrator**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="client" type="win32"/> 

   <description>Westwell Contoso</description> 

   <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Most people run their services either as the limited **LocalService** or **NetworkService** accounts.